# Missing Field - Customer Actived

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-account

Recently, my Magento site was moved to a new server and the developer messed up big style. I am trying to fix and found a major field missing.
V1.9.2.0
In the customer account information section, there was a field named - Is Activated (I think), where you make customers active or not.
This field is missing and now no new customers can be activated.
I have a few custom mods that were installed but to my knowledge, these don't affect this as it worked perfectly normal previously.

Any ideas how to fix this?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: when create new customer in magento at time by default is active value set 1 and not checked any where in code

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this a different way, using the way that is already available to me.

From the main menu tabs across the top, choose:

Customers

Manage Customers (All customers appear)

Find the customer to activate and on the left hand side, put a tick in the checkbox (you can do single or multiple amounts of customers at once)

On the right hand side is an ACTIONS field, use the dropdown to choose CUSTOMER ACTIVATED

A new field appears named CUSTOMER ACTIVATED = No
Change this field to YES (with notification)
Hit the SUBMIT button

Customer is now activated and will receive notification.

Answer (score 0):

Default Magento is not giving is_active field in admin. In the database table you will find this field but for use of this field need to do custom additional code.